# How can I decompile .pyc files from Python 3.10?

Tags: python, decompiler, python-3.10, pyc

I did try uncompyle6, decompyl3, and others, but none of them worked with 3.10. Is it even possible to do this right now?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: python 3.10 is very fresh version and you may need to wait for tools for this version.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use pycdc.
Github: https://github.com/zrax/pycdc

```
git clone https://github.com/zrax/pycdc
cd pycdc
cmake .
make
make check
pycdc C:\Users\Bobby\example.pyc
```

Comment: To use pycdc you'll have to to clone the repo, cd into that dir, run 'cmake .' (you might have to install cmake), then run 'make', then 'make checks', then you can run pycdc. It worked for me with Python 3.10 bytecode.

Comment: These instructions do not work on windows.

Comment: @CodeMed: As others have subsequently posted, if you don't have `make` available, `MSBuild.exe pycdc.vcxproj` should build it, and the resulting `pycdc.exe` executable should do the same job.

Comment: pycdc is an executable, so calling it with python will throw an error. Just use `pycdc /path/to/your/pyc` as the last step.

Answer (score 2):

on Windows (presume you have both Cmake and MSBuild.exe)

```
git clone https://github.com/zrax/pycdc
cd pycdc
cmake .
MSBuild.exe pycdc.vcxproj
cd pycdc/Debug
pycdc.exe yourfile.pyc
```