# How I can decompile byte code to .py in python 3.11

Tags: bytecode, decompiling, python-3.11

I lost my source code and tried to retrieve it again. I have extracted the cyp file and used tool to decompile it back to .py, but unfortunately, I have gotten this error:

`nvalid pyc/pyo file - Magic value mismatch!`

Is there any tool for code written with python 3.11.5?

I wnat to get my .py back.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I decompile .pyc files from Python 3.10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71278961/how-can-i-decompile-pyc-files-from-python-3-10)

Comment: pycdc doesn't appear to support the new 3.8 opcodes: ROT_FOUR, BEGIN_FINALLY, CALL_FINALLY and POP_FINALLY. If anyone figured it out please post.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this sugestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71278961/how-can-i-decompile-pyc-files-from-python-3-10#:%7E:text=2%20Answers&text=To%20use%20pycdc%20you%27ll,me%20with%20Python%203.10%20bytecode.), i've never tried but may work. The latests commits add suport for python3.11

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).